# Converting DateTimeOffset string value to Date object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm using ASP.NET and I have the following string:

```
2018-12-04T13:53:42.6785734+07:00
```

I want to convert the string to Date object and format the output string.

My goal: `04/12/2018 13:53:42`

I've tried this way but it logged with the wrong result:

```js
var dt = new Date('2018-12-04T13:53:42.6785734+07:00'); 

var day = dt.getDay(),
    month = dt.getMonth(),
    year = dt.getFullYear(),
    hours = dt.getHours(),
    minutes = dt.getMinutes(),
    seconds = dt.getSeconds();
    
// 2/11/2018 13:53:42    
console.log(day + '/' + month + '/' + year + ' ' + hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds);
```

Comment: `getDate()` not `getDay()`. Also, in JS month start from `0`. So you will have to use `getMonth() + 1`

Comment: It will return the date correctly but with current timezone not the timezone of string received. For example, if your current timezone is +8:00, the timezone +7:00 will converted to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var dt = new Date('2018-12-04T13:53:42.6785734+07:00'); 

var day = dt.getDate(),
month = dt.getMonth(),
year = dt.getFullYear(),
hours = dt.getHours(),
minutes = dt.getMinutes(),
seconds = dt.getSeconds();

// 2/11/2018 13:53:42    
console.log(day + '/' + (month + 1) + '/' + year + ' ' + hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds);
```

I changed your code like this, try:

```
var dt = new Date('2018-12-04T13:53:42.6785734+07:00'); 

var day = dt.getDate(),
month = dt.getMonth(),
year = dt.getFullYear(),
hours = dt.getHours(),
minutes = dt.getMinutes(),
seconds = dt.getSeconds();

console.log(day + '/' + (month + 1) + '/' + year + ' ' + hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds);
```

Answer (score 0):

Would it be acceptable to just manipulate the original string directly without converting to a date object like so? I can really tell what the test cases would be but assuming that the hour number is the same length (04,12) I think the following code should work.

```
let dt = '2018-12-04T13:53:42.6785734+07:00';
let  dArr = dt.substr(0,10).split('-');
let year = dArr[0];
let month = dArr[1];
let day = dArr[2];
let time = dt.substr(11,8);

let str = month+'/'+day+'/'+year+' '+time;

console.log(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following are arrays starting at 0
`getDay()`  Get the weekday as a number (0-6)
`getDate()` Get the day as a number (1-31)
`getMonth()`    Get the month as a number (0-11)

```
var dt = new Date("2018-12-04T13:53:42.6785734+07:00"); 

var day = returnDay(),
month = returnMonth(),
year = dt.getFullYear(),
hours = dt.getHours(),
minutes = dt.getMinutes(),
seconds = dt.getSeconds(),


function returnDay(){
  var d = (dt.getDate() < 10) ? "0" + (dt.getDate()): dt.getDate();
  return d;
}

function returnMonth(){
  var m = (dt.getMonth() + 1 < 10) ? "0" + (dt.getMonth()+ 1):dt.getMonth()+ 1;
  return m;
}

//04/12/2018 8:53:42
console.log(day + '/' + month + '/' + year + ' ' + hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds);
```

see for more info:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp

Answer (score 0):

Slice it, I have used jQuery in the example because I have used in in another project and this code was just a part of a component, but it should not matter much

```
var getTimeOnly = new Date().getTime();
var fullDate = new Date($.now()).toString();
var datePartialTime = fullDate.slice(16, 25);
var datePartialDate = fullDate.slice(0, 16);



$('a').html( "on " + datePartialDate + 'at ' + datePartialTime);
```

Link to pen

https://codepen.io/damPop/pen/zMzBGN